# How to move from filtered results page after opening the particular records

Tags: angular

Initially we have 50 records in main page and,
we filter/search the particular records from main page and so we get some records like 5 records after search on main page, and then we open one records among the 5 records ( filtered results) into new page.

From particular new page, suppose we want to go back to the previous page like filtered page (where we have 5 records) instead of main page.

So how can we do this?

Please help on this.

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe have a service that maintains the current filtered list and filters, and have the list component gets its data from there. That way state is maintained across navigation and can be restored.

Comment: Either a state management system (like NgRx) or use routing parameters to describe the set filters